# Route traffic individually

Tags: networking, ssh, smtp

My schools smtp server is only available while Im at school.

I can proxy to a server at school through an ssh tunnel but then ALL of my traffic.

I want to tunnel one thing only (The smtp connection)? any ideas?

Comment: Why is your schools SMTP server only available when you are there?  
1) Limited access because it is on a non routable IP?   
2) or can you reach it just fine but does it deny access except when you are at school?

Point 2 can be solved with authentication. Ask your school IT staff for the right way to do this.  Point one require a VPN or a tunnel. An SSH tunnel with a proper entry (for a single host) in the routing table should do.

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
ssh -L 25:smtp.school.com:25 server.school.com
```

This will forward port 25 on your machine through the machine you have access to at school to the SMTP server. Replace 25 with the port number your SMTP server uses if different. Now you can connect to your own machine to send mail, and it will forward to the SMTP server transparently.